# Setting property for two backgrounds using css

Tags: css, background-image

I'm trying to set two backgrounds to my input, one before, then the text value that user will input, then the unity (it is the second background).

I've tried to do two different classes, but just the first was used.

Then I've seen that we can set two backgrounds separating them by a comma, but I do not know how to set different position for the second one.

My CSS looks like:

```
.icontaille {
    background: url('../images/taille-16.png'),url('../images/taille-cm16.png') no-repeat scroll 02px 01px !important;
    padding-left: 30px;
    width: 170px !important
}
```

I've tried also:

```
 background: url('../images/taille-16.png') no-repeat scroll 02px 01px !important,url('../images/taille-cm16.png') no-repeat scroll 52px 01px !important;
```

but it does not work at all.

Comment: if you remove the first `!important` from your second example it works.

Comment: 01px is an incorrect value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you trying to do something like that:

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/63XrT/1/)

```
.icontaille{
    background-image: url('../images/taille-16.png'), url('../images/taille-cm16.png') 
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
    background-position: top left, top right;
    padding-left:30px;    
    width:170px !important
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the position for the images as shown below.

```
#example1 {
width: 500px;
height: 250px;
background-image: url('image1.png'), url('image2.png');
background-position: center bottom, left top;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can apply multiple backgrounds before and after the text inside text box by applying `padding` on both sides and positioning the backgrounds in that space accordingly, as follows:

```
input{
  padding:25px 50px;
  background: url(''../images/taille-16.png'') no-repeat, url('../images/taille-cm16.png') no-repeat;
  background-position: left, right;
  background-size:30px, 30px;
}
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kqFe7/)

Read more about [Using multiple CSS backgrounds @ MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_multiple_backgrounds)